# How do I create an mp4 signed url

Tags: php, url, mp4

I wanna create a system in which i can either authenticate or deny the user from accessing an mp4 file and downloading it

How may I approach such a result

by signed url i mean something like this:

```
www.example.com/videos/ldwdk.mp4?token=112233445566778899
```

and then I can use server sided language (php) in order to authenticate or deny it, but obviously i cannot code php in mp4 files?

Comment: You can. Use htaccess to block the access to the mp4 files. Php can output all kind of files you want. There are a lot of answers out there, just search for them

Comment: @Jonasw Okay so I'll output the mp4 file using php because php has access and the client doesn't due to htaccess configurations that i'll make??